# I want to remove PHP-5.3. completely from my machine after  make it from source

Tags: php, linux, make

I want to remove PHP-5.3. completely from my machine after  make it from source.
how can this be done?
When I try make uninstall I get:

make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.

Comment: This is probably more superuser than stackoverflow. Are you trying to remove the source code? Did you do a `make install` and are now trying to undo it?

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you use some linux flavor (I'll assume it's debian based) you could use a tool like checkinstall ( http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/ ) which will create a package with all the files resulting from the make install procedure. In this way you obtain a list of files along with their path. Now you can either delete them manually one by one or install the created package overwriting the existing files and then removing it using the purge option.

Comment: it also works in fedora based distros iic

Comment: yes, you can also create rpms